# Word for a transformation without an origin

Tags: geometry, terminology, transformation, tiling

Is there a precise term for a transformation which does not have an origin? For example, a translation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or a deformation which is equally applied to each tile in a tiled plane, so that it looks the same everywhere? A rotation or shear would not count, since geometry further away from the origin gets deformed more than geometry near the origin.

Comment: Maybe an homothecy?

Comment: [Affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) might fit your needs

Comment: Both "transformation" and "origin" are terms you might want to explain in more detail. Your example of a tiled plane in particular suggests something not covered by the most common classes of transformations.